# Managing asp.net membership in production

Tags: .net, wcf, deployment, configuration, asp.net-membership

I have been using the 'Web Site Administration Tool' that you can bring up in Visual Studio to manage users and roles in our dev and staging environment.

Currently we have no way of managing users and roles when the app goes to our production servers. for now we have been calling stored-procedure in the membership database to manually create initial users and roles which was a very tedious and error prone task. 
I tried looking for management tools but couldn't find anything that is up-to-date.

what do you use to setup the initial users and roles in an asp.net membership enabled application?

ps. These are all WCF applications so I can't use asp.net membership controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *should* build an application that can be used for this purpose, either a local client that can be run from a desktop or a hosted asp.net application.

That being said, as a quick and dirty solution you can try this:

Deploy web site administration tool to production:
http://tech.chezporlier.com/node/3